# Default value of Android preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

How do you get the default value of an Android preference defined in XML? I don't want to repeat the definition of the default value in both the code and the preferences XML.

Comment: post your xml preferences file, do you mean a PreferenceScreen

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can define default value in resources (`/values/bool.xml`):

```
<resources>
    <bool name="mypreference_default">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Use the value in the `preferences.xml`:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="@bool/mypreference_default"
    android:key="mypreference"
    android:title="@string/mypreference_title" />
```

Then use in code:

```
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Boolean value = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.mypreference_default);
Boolean b = p.getBoolean("mypreference", value);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. One more hint: Define the resources not in strings.xml but in a separate file (e.g. constants.xml) to avoid localization.

Comment: @schnatterer: moving the strings to a different file wont avoid localization. The `strings.xml` filename is just convention. Any resource can be localized by placing it in the correct `res/` subfolder. Although placing default settings into a separate resource file is probably a good idea.

Comment: @AlexMDC You're right. I' was just trying to establish a best practice in order to decrease the risk of "unintended translation".

Comment: You can put them in values/attrs.xml . This way, they won't be translated

Comment: Or you can do:

<string translatable="false"

Comment: what is the `Boolean value` is called from Activity, what should I replace `context` with?

Comment: @Si8, replace with "this" or just remove - it is not needed when called from Activity.

Comment: I think this is a make up way to resovle the problem Android API introduced. The root reason for this problem is Android API used two DEFAULT values.

Answer (score 13):

First you need to define default values in your preference XML file.
Then you can populate preferences with default values in your main Activity by calling:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
```

When you need to retrieve a some preference just call:

```
int value = prefs.getInt("key", null);
```

Since your preferences are populated you won't get `null` value.

Comment: This still doesn't protect against the possible situation where someone down the line removes a preference from the XML and forgets to update the Java code requesting it. In that situation, the application will still compile, but you will end up with a NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but then a Functional Test should be written to test if all needed preferences are retrieved from XML.

Comment: this actually didn't work at all for me.  the default values were not set after calling this method.

Comment: @moonlightcheese have you found a solution for your problem? I'm stuck at the same point - I call the method but the values aren't set.

Comment: Note that it seems that you should actually call `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues` with the last parameter as `true`. In fact, if you have multiple preference files this is crucial to the second file being loaded at all. Call `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues` on all preferences files in the main activity.

Comment: Thanks. I use a combination of Pawel's answer and your `setDefaultValues` method.

Comment: Thank you. I needed to access default values before running Preferences Activity, so I moved `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, true);` to `onCreate` of rootactivity (`MainActivity`)

Answer (score 1):

Create `integer.xml` under `res/values` to store integer constants.

In `prefereces.xml` reference `"@integer/default_brightness"`

In code `context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.default_brightness)`